# Akka cluster configuration

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I get this error:

```
[ERROR] [05/04/2018 11:21:26.747] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] 
[akka://default/system/cluster/core/daemon/joinSeedNodeProcess-1] bug 
in method caller: not valid to create ConfigValue from: ConfigString("")
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$BugOrBroken: bug in method caller: not valid to create ConfigValue from: ConfigString("")
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl.fromAnyRef(ConfigImpl.java:275)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.PropertiesParser.fromPathMap(PropertiesParser.java:152)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.PropertiesParser.fromPathMap(PropertiesParser.java:82)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl.fromAnyRef(ConfigImpl.java:260)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl.fromPathMap(ConfigImpl.java:200)
at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseMap(ConfigFactory.java:855)
at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseMap(ConfigFactory.java:866)
at akka.cluster.JoinConfigCompatChecker$.filterWithKeys(JoinConfigCompatChecker.scala:104)
at akka.cluster.JoinSeedNodeProcess$$anonfun$receive$4.applyOrElse(ClusterDaemon.scala:1514)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
at akka.cluster.JoinSeedNodeProcess.aroundReceive(ClusterDaemon.scala:1490)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:588)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

When trying to create a (local only) akka cluster. I stripped my config down to a few lines in application.conf:

```
akka {
    actor {
        provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    }
    cluster {
        seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]
    }
}
```

And get my error when starting the ActorSystem:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    ActorSystem.create()
}
```

I am using akka version 2.5.12 with scala version 2.12.

Comment: Your config looks correct. It looks like a classpath issue with an invalid issue version of type safe config. What else do you have on your classpath?

Comment: You were correct. I used a package `com.twitter chill-akka` version `0.9.2` which loads `com.typesafe config` version `1.2.1`. That one was ruining my party

Answer (score 2):

So I was including `com.twitter chill-akka` version `0.9.2` in my maven pom. This includes `com.typesage config` version `1.2.1`. The version needed by `com.typesafe.akka akka-actor-typed` version `2.5.12` is `1.3.2`

So now my maven include looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
    <artifactId>chill-akka_${scala.version}</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```